# Permission issues viewing photos uploaded with php

Tags: php, permissions, image-uploading

I'm following a tutorial for uploading image files using php on udemy. I can choose an image and upload it to a folder without any problems.

When I click on the image after it has been uploaded to the folder, windows photo viewer says: "photo.png It appears that you don't have permission to view this file. Check the permissions and try again".

When I checked permissions it said "You must have read permissions to view the properties of this file".

I used the chmod function set to 0755, which allows the owner to read and write, and lets everyone else read it. I tried changing the chmod codes but it didn't help.

I'm thinking it has something to do with my server permissions, but can't find any solution on google. My images are uploaded to Abyss Web Server.

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function upload_file() {
    //setup
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $target_dir = 'uploads/';
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $max_file_size = 5000000; //5mb
    $allowed_file_types = array('application/pdf; charset=binary');
    $allowed_image_types = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);

    //check if image type is allowed
    $image_check = getimagesize($tmp_name);

    if(! in_array($image_check[2], $allowed_image_types)) {
        //if not allowed image check if allowed file type
        exec('file -bi' . $tmp_name, $file_check);

        if(! in_array($file_check[0], $allowed_file_types)) {
            return 'This file type is not allowed';
        }
    }

    //check if file already exists
    if(file_exists($target_file)) {
        return 'Sorry that file already exists';
    }

    //check file size
    if(file_exists($target_file)) {
        return 'Sorry this file is too big';
    }

    //store the file
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file)) {
        chmod($target_file, 0644);
        return 'Your file was uploaded';
    }
    else {
        return 'There was a problem storing your file. Try again?';
    }
}

if(! empty($_FILES)) {
    echo upload_file();
}

?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" Value="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Try to print the image in some random page using HTML and see if it loads it and shows it. If that does happen, then you might be facing a _hotlink protection_ issue, which can be resolved by editing the `.htaccess` file within the directory or the closest parent directory. For the record, I never used Abyss Web Server nor have I ever heard of it.

Comment: Ah thank you, it works fine when called as a html/php file, just can't access it locally which isn't too bad. Thank you for suggesting that! :) :)

Comment: Okay then! That's called _hotlink protection_. Some people don't like their copyrighted images to be accessed, so one way to avoid inexperienced people (let's say, _"people in userland"_) from doing that is to enable this protection. cPanel, for example, provides a tool for this. You can see if a hidden file called `.htaccess` is somewhere in your server and delete it or modify it. That, if you ever really need to access it that way. Should I write some kind of answer just to close the question formally or do you feel like your question was not answered?

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find the .htaccess file in the file directory :) cpanel it is :) and sure, it would be great to mark it as best answer :) Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to hear that. Thank you for being so kind too, I don't see that very often here. Good luck with your project and learning on Udemy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since loading the file using a custom made HTML page specifically for testing motives does show the image correctly, then it's most likely a *hotlink protection* issue. (This was found out after a few comments to the question).

In cPanel, for example, there is a tool to manage this feature and it revolves around the usage of a file called `.htaccess`. This file is used for a lot of things in the web development world.

Some people don't like their copyrighted images to be accessed, so one way to avoid inexperienced people (let's say, *"people in userland"*) from doing that is to enable this protection. This works for any given file extension that you set it up to.

One way to address this issue is to go to cPanel and disable (or modify accordingly) the Hotlink Protection feature. Another way, is to find the `.htaccess` file that is causing the issue, which requires understanding the way it works and the syntax it uses.